# can't ssh into remote machine using blowfish

Tags: ssh

I have a remote machine I need to `ssh` to using `blowfish` encryption. I set everything up on my laptop on my previous `distro` and I have in my `config` file setup for `blowfish`. Today I install `Ubuntu Gnome` and when I try to `ssh` to whatever machine I get an error

```
/home/yotam/.ssh/config line 43: Bad cipher 'blowfish'.
```

I searched what I need to install, but it seems that this should come with the `distro`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no cipher called `blowfish` in SSHv2. It was only in the old protocol SSHv1, which is gone (hopefully also on Ubuntu).

SSHv2 has cipher called `blowfish-cbc` as pointed out in manual page for `ssh_config` (always good place to start).

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu 16.04 you can try this (replace user and ip)

```
ssh -XC -c aes128-gcm@openssh.com youruser@1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Cipher performance compare: https://blog.famzah.net/2015/06/26/openssh-ciphers-performance-benchmark-update-2015/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is delete any lines containing:

```
cipher blowfish
```

from the ~/.ssh/config file, which in the case of the original poster is line 43, as indicated by the error message. However, this error message is misleading; see the answer on https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1281705

The probable cause is that you set up your SSH connection some time ago, or used an old tutorial, and now you upgraded to a version of SSH that doesn't permit this option.